# Do URIs used in RDF need to be dereferenceable in Jena?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, semantic-web, linked-data

I'm looking over the Jena tutorial, [*An Introduction to RDF and the Jena RDF API*](http://jena.sourceforge.net/tutorial/RDF_API/index.html#ch-Reading%20RDF), and am specifically looking at [Tutorial01.java](http://jena.sourceforge.net/src-examples/jena/examples/rdf/Tutorial01.java).  The PersonURI is very vague, as it is defined as:

```
static String personURI    = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith";
```

Does this URI need to dereferenceable?  If so, do all RDF implementation require a web server?  Lastly, what is served up at that URI if it does need to be dereferenced and returned?

Comment: I've edited the question a little bit to fix up some terminology.  _Resolving_ is something that's typically done with relative URLs/URIs/IRIs.  E.g., we might resolve `foo.html` relative some base `http://example.org/` to get `http://example.org/foo.html`.  Making an HTTP request (or a request via another protocol) for a representation of a URI is _dereferencing_ the URI.  The question, then, is whether URIs used as identifiers in RDF must be dereferenceable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it does not. Actually, regardless of Jena, **a URI does not have to be resolvable** anyway. A URI is an identifier of an entity. **A URL is always a URI. This does not mean that a URI is necessarily a URL.**

Copying from the [RDF primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#identifiers):

> As discussed in Section 2.1, the Web provides a general form of identifier, called the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI), for identifying (naming) resources on the Web. Unlike URLs, **URIs are not limited to identifying things that have network locations**, or use other computer access mechanisms.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Nice way to answer with logic 'URL is always URI, but URI is not URL'.

Answer (score 4):

It does not need to be resolvable.

That's good practice for publishing on the web but Jena does not look names up just because you use them.